# Remove string from line in shell and python

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, awk

I have a log file in which we are getting ip address at wrong place.

```
cat test.sh
173.36.31.10 dasdsafafa fafsafaasfa fafasfaa173.36.31.10
173.36.31.11 dasdsafafa fafsafaasfa fafasfaa173.36.31.11
```

if you see my above script it has ip address twice which is wrong in my case. I want to write a script that deletes 2nd id address.

I am thinking of getting `cat test.sh | awk '{print $1}'` ip address by doing this but I am not sure how to delete the second ipaddress.

I want to do it in both shell and python, can someone help me?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Couple of things: Are all strings of that length and format? and Why do you want this in both python and shell?

Comment: Why tag it with awk if you want "shell" and python? Usually when people say shell they mean all standard UNIX tools which includes awk so then why bother with python? Or are you saying you want 2 different solutions - one in shell/awk and the other in python?

Answer (score 4):

Using this as the test file:

```
$ cat test.sh
173.36.31.10 dasdsafafa fafsafaasfa fafasfaa173.36.31.10
173.36.31.11 dasdsafafa fafsafaasfa fafasfaa173.36.31.11
```

#### Using awk

Here is one method from removing the second occurrence of the IP from the end of the line.

```
$ awk '{sub($1"$", "")} 1' test.sh
173.36.31.10 dasdsafafa fafsafaasfa fafasfaa
173.36.31.11 dasdsafafa fafsafaasfa fafasfaa
```

In awk, `$1` designates the first field on the line.  Thus, if the first field is repeated at the end of the line, `sub($1"$", "")` will remove it.

In more detail, for regular expressions, `$` means end-of-the-line.  Thus `$1"$"` will match any re-occurrence of the first field at the end of the line. The command `sub($1"$", "")` replaces such a re-occurrence with an empty string.

#### Using shell

```
$ while read ip rest; do echo "$ip ${rest%$ip}"; done <test.sh
173.36.31.10 dasdsafafa fafsafaasfa fafasfaa
173.36.31.11 dasdsafafa fafsafaasfa fafasfaa
```

#### Using sed

This looks for any line for which the first word on the line is repeated at the end of the line.  If so, the repeat is removed:

```
$ sed -r 's/([^ ]*)( .*)\1$/\1\2/' test.sh
173.36.31.10 dasdsafafa fafsafaasfa fafasfaa
173.36.31.11 dasdsafafa fafsafaasfa fafasfaa
```

#### Using python

```
with open('test.sh') as fhandle:
    for line in fhandle:
        line = line.rstrip()
        ip=line.split()[0]
        if line.endswith(ip):
            line=line[:-len(ip)]
        print(line)
```

This produces the same output.

Comment: Question, what if the ip address is in the **middle of the string?** how can we deal with that?

Answer (score 1):

**Using Perl**

```
cat test.sh | perl -ne 's/^(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)(.*)\1$/$1$2/; print'
```